# chrome.tabCapture.capture returning NULL stream

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been searching around a bit, but didn't find any solution to this issue.
I'm not sure why but the `stream` which I'm getting is `null`.

As you can see in the code bellow, I'm not using `browserAction` but instead I'm sending a message to the extension and then calling `requestCurrentTabCapture`

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {

    switch(msg.type){
      case 'SS_TAB_REQUEST':
        alert("SS_TAB_REQUEST");
        requestCurrentTabCapture(port, msg);
        break;
      case 'SS_TAB_CANCEL':
        break;
      default:
    }
  });
});

function requestCurrentTabCapture(port, msg){
  //chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
    //chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tab) {
        alert(tab);
        chrome.tabCapture.capture(
          {
            video: true, audio: true,
            videoConstraints: {
             mandatory: {
               chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
               minWidth: 16,
               minHeight: 9,
               maxWidth: 1280,
               maxHeight: 720,
               maxFrameRate: 60,  // Note: Frame rate is variable (0 <= x <= 60).
             },
           },
          },
          function(stream) {
            alert(stream); //<-- NULL
            if (!stream) {
             console.error('Error starting tab capture: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message || 'UNKNOWN'));
           }
          }
        );      
    });


    chrome.tabCapture.onStatusChanged.addListener(function (info){
            alert("status: "+info.status); //<-- not shown
            alert("tabId: "+info.tabId); //<-- not shown
            alert("fullscreen: "+info.fullscreen); //<-- not shown
    });
}
```

Permissions are as follows:

```
"permissions": [
 "desktopCapture",
 "<all_urls>",
 "tabs",
"activeTab",
 "tabCapture"
]
```

Comment: In the absence of `currentWindow: true` chrome.tabs.query will return the active debugger window if you have it focused. Also, are there any errors in the [background page console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913799/google-chrome-firefox-do-not-see-extension-output-in-console/38920982)?

Comment: Thanks for the link, i see `Error starting tab capture: Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured.` error

Comment: Well, the error is self-explanatory, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture#method-capture).

Comment: `Capture can only be started on the currently active tab after the extension has been invoked` ? The error is printed when i'm using `console.error()`  in the callback. Please check the edited question.

Comment: `invoked` is explained in the activeTab link there. It means the user should interact with your extension explicitly.

Comment: hi, I added the logic for `pageAction`, I'm receiving a valid `stream` object. but when I send `port.postMessage(msg)` and the msg contains `msg.stream = stream` I'm not receiving the stream in my webpage js file. `msg.streamId` is coming like `[Object]` and no data in it

Comment: That's because messaging stringifies objects with JSON.stringify so only simple objects may be passed. You'll need to process the stream where you get it.